# Key-value list in fastlane

Tags: ruby, fastlane

Hi I write fastlane script and I need in key-value list.

I need in same list with key-value
I try type:

```
default_platform(:android)
platform :android do
    lane : getSomething do |options|
        puts options[:type]
        puts options[:whitelabel]
        array={"samekey":"samevalue"}
        array[:options[:whitelabel]]
    end
end
```

where `whitelabeloptions[:whitelabel] = samekey`
I get error

> `[]': [!] no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You have a stray space in `lane : getSomething`, perhaps you mean `lane :getSomething` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main reason:
`key` have `sym` type, but I try search `string` type
so solution:

```
default_platform(:android)
platform :android do
    lane :getSomething do |options|
        collection = { "key1":"value1",
                "key2":"value2"}
        key=options[:param1]
        if collection [!key.to_sym].nil?
            collection [key.to_sym].to_s
        else
            UI.user_error!("myMessage")
        end
    end
end
```